# Sendmail via php with dynamic url doesn't work

Tags: php, echo, href, sendmail

I have a big problem! I need to track what the users are doing on my site. As a way to resolve it I crated a sendmail function in order to send me an email every time a user clicks on a button. The code is this:

```
<div class="buy">
<a onclick="target='_blank'" href="<?php echo $this->product['from'];?>">

<?php
// The message
$message = "A new buy";
$link = $this->product['from'];

// Send
mail('xxx@mail.com', '@buy PRODUCT', $message, $link);
?> 

<img src="http://xxx.com/data/images/xxx.jpg" alt="Comprar"       />                            
</a>
</div>
```

The message I receive is

```
"A new buy

"
```

And it should look like:

```
"A new buy

http://www.xxxx.com"
```

Anyone can help me with this problem?

Comment: RTFM: http://php.net/mail  and examine what the allowed function parameters are

Answer (score 0, accepted):

mail('xxx@mail.com', '@buy PRODUCT', $message.$link);

Answer (score 1):

You need 2 only pass one message parameter.

```
$message = $message.$this->product['from'];
mail('xxx@mail.com', '@buy PRODUCT', $message);
```

Comment: Also the fourth parameter is the _header_

Comment: Thanks for ur answers, now it sends the correct url to the mail, but in the site shows this error:  Notice: Undefined variable: message in /var/www/html/application/modules/default/views/default/prod/prodDetail.phtml on line 132

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
mail('xxx@mail.com', '@buy PRODUCT', $message.$link);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just concatenate any data related to your message to your $message variable and just pass that $message variable into the mail function. For example: `$message = $message." Link: ".$link` and then `mail('xxx@mail.com', $message)`